# PostgreSQL - Using COALESCE keyword in SSIS

Tags: postgresql, ssis

When I am trying to use the COALESCE key word in an OLE DB Source control, it always returns a negative number in the results set.

I am using a Native OLE DB\PostgreSQL Native Provider as a connection to the database and other key words are working correctly.

I run the query in PGAdminIII and it returns a numeric data type.

I re-enginered the query to use a case when statement, but its still producing a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

We spoke to the PGNP team and it was a problem with the provider that we are using. Its a known problem and will be resolved shortly.